# @media or expression and max-width

Tags: css, media-queries

let me say as first I am a CSS noob. I can freely accept any blaming

```
@media (max-width: 735px) {... }
@media (min-width: 735px) {... }

@media (width: 320px) {... }

@media (width: 360px) {... }
@media (width: 375px) {... }
@media (width: 414px) {... }
```

I have these things for able to make it sensitive.
I wanted to use `max-width` but failed not sure why but browser always choose another `max-width` expression and executes it so I just collected the mobile phone's width and made this.

And also I want to send same content to who has 360px and 320px is there any "or" expression may be I can minify it.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correct from your question, you can add the following `media query`.

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 360px) {
  html { color: blue; }
}
```

I recommended using a different approach, either **mobile first** or **desktop first** using media queries. In that way you can simply address the correct layout to a lot of people without writing exceptions.

**Mobile first**

```
html { color: purple; }

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  html { color: black; }
}

/* And go up the road */
```

**Desktop first**

```
html { color: purple; }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  html { color: black; }
} 

/* And go down the road */
```

Comment: neither @ media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 360px) {
nor 
@ media (min-width: 320px) or (max-width: 360px) {
doesn't work

Comment: This `@media (max-width: 735px) {... }` will override the other settings, because it's true. Please use a different approach, either mobile first or desktop first to achieve what you want.

Comment: @MustafaMarsliTopaloğlu Depends on your needs of course. Glad it is resolved.